# batch file read file line by line and manupulate

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have a file `input.txt` with following text in it:

> ```
> sample_name
> sample_age
> sample_height
> ```

I want to read the `input.txt` file line by line and save it in a temporary variable and echo it.

Code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type "input.txt"') do echo a= %%a & set temp=%%a & echo temp= %temp% 
pause
```

Expected output:

> ```
> a= sample_name
> temp= sample_name
> a= sample_age
> temp= sample_age
> a= sample_height
> temp= sample_height
> ```

Gained:

> ```
> a= sample_name
> a= sample_age
> a= sample_height
> ```

So for the gained output is it visible that `for` loop is reading the lines but the problem is somewhere assigning it to `temp`. Any solution?

Also, is it possible to save the lines in separate variables? Something like:

> ```
> name=sample_name
> age=sample_age
> height=sample_height
> ```

Comment: I'm not getting your output. I am also getting `temp` related output (to what it was set before entering the loop: in my case the temporary folder). I see that you're setting the [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), but not using it. Modify your `echo temp ...` command to `echo temp= !temp!`.

Comment: for `echo temp= !temp!` I get  temp= !temp!.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange... with the command modified to: `for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type "input.txt"') do echo a= %%a & set temp=%%a & echo temp= !temp!` (everything else untouched) , I get the expected output. I tried it on _W10(x64)_. Sure you're running the same code posted?

Comment: AAMOI, `temp` is not a good name for a user-set variable as it is set by the system to point to a temporary-files directory.

Comment: thanks CristiFati. !var! works. it seems the variable temp was creating the problem so changing it works fine as  @Magoo said.